# where to find the source code to edit title?

Tags: magento-1.8, page-title

where to edit and the find the source code of this.As magento codes are difficult to understand.

[image]

Comment: is this specific to the admin section? what do you want to do with the titles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a better way to do this but this should get you there: 
Magento\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\main.xml

Line 57

```
<action method="setTitle" translate="title"><title>Magento Admin</title></action>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you wish to edit title then you can edit it from Magento admin simply with

```
<title>
< ?php echo ($this->getForcedTitle()) ? Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/title_prefix').' '.$this->getForcedTitle().' '.Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/title_suffix') : $this->getTitle() ?>
</title>
```

or if you don’t wish to use title prefix/sufix added from Magento admin, simply with

```
<title>
< ?php echo ($this->getForcedTitle()) ? $this->getForcedTitle() : $this->getTitle() ?>
</title>
```

and now just set “forced” title for pages through layout files

```
<reference name="head">
<action method="setForcedTitle"><title>Account Dashboard</title></action>
</reference>
```